# SharePoint or AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

Currently I'm working in a project which is a SharePoint 2013 sandbox solution, i.e. the custom code is deprecated, leaving with just the front-end JS development which we have implemented in using Angular.
In SharePoint I'm unaware of any server side coding.

> So what should be my primary focus with career perspective **SharePoint** or **Angular JS**. Please help. Should I start learning SharePoint server-side concepts or invest my time in improvising my Angular concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be aware of client side code and server side code both. As it depends on your project requirements. As now days client side technology is preferable as it has not much overhead on server also not so many round trips to server. but one should be aware of in both aspects.
Angular JS is a framework you should know JavaScript, jquery and any one JS framework to work accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way that you can develop server side code and there are lots of tools given by different parties to do the server side code easily. But client side programming is more crucial these days as limited number of tools and knowledge on that area is not very good among the lot of programmers. So my opinion is to learn both but give more focus on client side programming. And make Anguer Js your specialty :)